# Knockout, Require and Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, requirejs, jquery-select2

So here's an interesting issue I came up against with knockout, require and select2.  I had to share, because this took so darn long to figure it out.  What I was trying to do was have a dynamically created select2 select list created from a observable array.  The array contained an item called, let's say Id.  The select list looked like this:

```
<select data-bind="
          options: $root.Items,
          optionsValue: 'Id', 
          optionsText: 'FullName', 
          value: Id,
          select2: {}"></select>
```

The binding handler looked like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.select2 = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            var obj = valueAccessor(),
                allBindings = allBindingsAccessor(),
                lookupKey = allBindings.lookupKey;
            $(element).select2(obj);
            if (lookupKey) {
                var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindings.value);
                $(element).select2('data', ko.utils.arrayFirst(obj.data.results, function (item) {
                    return item[lookupKey] === value;
                }));
            }

            ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
                $(element).select2('destroy');
            });
        },
        update: function (element) {
            $(element).trigger('change');
        }
    };
```

The problem I ran into was this.  The update method would never get called when I selected a new item from the dynamically created select list.  So, what I had to do was:

```
<select data-bind="
              options: $root.Items,
              optionsValue: 'Id', 
              optionsText: 'FullName', 
              value: Id,
              select2: Id"></select>
```

And the binding handled needed to be changed to:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.select2 = {
            init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
                var obj = valueAccessor(),
                    allBindings = allBindingsAccessor(),
                    lookupKey = allBindings.lookupKey;
                $(element).select2({});

                if (lookupKey) {
                    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindings.value);
                    $(element).select2('data', ko.utils.arrayFirst(obj.data.results, function(item) {
                        return item[lookupKey] === value;
                    }));
                }

                ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
                    $(element).select2('destroy');
                });
            },
            update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
                $(element).on("change", function () {
                    var id = $(this).val();
                    var valAccesor = valueAccessor();
                    if (valAccesor && id && id > 0)
                        valAccesor(id);
                });
            }
        };
```

As you can see, I had to tell the init function to create a select2 object from scratch by passing in a blank object {} and had to tell the update function which observable to listen to by passing in the Id as the observable to listen to.  Now, when the underlying select list change event fires, I tell the Id observable to update.

I hope this helps others, as I had many days and nights of banging my head against the screen trying to figure out why the underlying select would not fire the update method on the custom binding handler.

Excuse any typos or code errors...I'll update if anyone finds an issue, and I'm always willing to hear of any other more elegant solutions...I have yet to find one.

Comment: Could you summarize the problem a bit better somewhere?  I have used these three tools together multiple times without having to use any work arounds...

Comment: I use the same binding handler you first posted all the time with no issues. And I dont think update would fire unless your obserablearray was modified